# append button value or remove it from a div when it is checked / unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/1439/)

I got the jQueryui multiselect from [this site](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#callbacks). I have trouble finding the correct selector to append the button's value to a div area when it is checked and remove it when it's unchecked. According to the documentation, I need to use `click` function to check if an option is checked. Here is a [normal demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/1441/) that shows how appending text is supposed to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Failed Script:

```
var post_text = $('#post_text');

$("select").multiselect({
   selectedText: "# of # selected",
 click: function(event, ui){
     if($(this).find('input').is('.checked'))
     {
      post_text.append(ui.value);
     }
     else
     {
      post_text.remove(ui.value);
      }  
 }
});
```

HTML:

```
<select multiple>
<option value="A">Option 1</option>
<option value="B">Option 2</option>
<option value="C">Option 3</option>
<option value="D">Option 4</option>
<option value="E">Option 5</option>
<option value="F">Option 6</option>
</select>

<div id="post_text"></div>
```

Comment: The plugin file you are referencing is invalid. Check console for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove text using `remove()`, you need a element for that. I have added `<span>` in this case.

Try the below code,

```
var post_text = $('#post_text');

$("select").multiselect({
    selectedText: "# of # selected",
    click: function (event, ui) {
        ui.checked 
        ? post_text.append('<span>' + ui.value + '</span>') 

        : $('span:contains('+ui.value+')').remove();
    }
});
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhyp/1445/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("select").multiselect({
    selectedText: "# of # selected",
    click: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.checked) { //Use ui.checked
            var span = '<div id="' + ui.value + '">'+ ui.text +'</div>'; //create div/span for easy access
            post_text.append(span); //append it
        } else {
            post_text.find('#'+ui.value).remove(); //remove based on ui-value
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q9z4j/)